# How many requests per second does libmemcached can handle?

Tags: performance, ubuntu, memcached, libmemcache

I hava a linux server which has 2G memory/ Intel Core 2 Duo 2.4 GHz cpu, I am developing a networking system. I use

libmemcached/memcache to store and access packet info,  I want to know how many requests does

libmemcached can handle in a plain linux server ? thanks!

Comment: This is a NP question, do a bench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many things that could affect the request rate (CPU speed, other hardware drivers, exact kernel version, request size, cache hit rate, etc ad infinitum).  There's no such thing as a "plain linux server."

Since it sounds like you've got fixed hardware, your best bet is to test the hardware you've got, and see how well it performs under your desired load.